# Delegates and protocols objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I followed on some advice given on this very forum and I am still having difficulty

I have the following:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    @protocol UIViewForWheelProtocol

    - (void) returnImageNumber:(int)imgNum;

    @end


    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "UIViewForWheelProtocol.h";


    @interface UIViewForWheel : UIView {
        id<UIViewForWheelProtocol> delegate;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) id<UIViewForWheelProtocol> delegate;



    @implementation UIViewForWheel

    @synthesize delegate;

    -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
       int num =1 ;
       [self.delegate returnImageNumber:num];
    }

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIViewForWheel.h"
#import "UIViewForWheelProtocol.h"


@interface MainMenu : UIViewController <UIViewForWheelProtocol> {

}

-(void) returnImageNumber:(int)whichImage;

@end


    #import "MainMenu.h"


    @implementation MainMenu

    - (void) returnImageNumber:(int)whichImage
    {
        NSLog(@"HI %i", whichImage);
    }
```

HI 1 is not being displayed because although it is going to the touchesMoved function it is not going to the returnImageNumber in the MainMenu class.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Do you ever assign the MainMenu instance as the delegate for the UIViewForWheel?

Comment: I also dont see the interface declaration for `MainMenu`... where is that?

Comment: @ Marcelo, apparently no...what should I do please?

Comment: Well, you could have easily edited your old question instead of adding a new one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you have manually assigned the delegate for `UIViewForWheel`, and that `MainMenu` conforms to that protocol `UIViewForWheelProtocol`.

Comment: Like this: `UIViewForWheelProtocol p1 = [[MainMenu alloc] init]; myUiViewForWheel.delegate = p1;`

Comment: `MainMenu* p1 = [[MainMenu alloc] init]; myUiViewForWheel.delegate = p1;` or `id<UIViewForWheelProtocol> p1 = [[MainMenu alloc] init]; myUiViewForWheel.delegate = p1;`